# how to set mysql general_log_file path to shared folder in laravel homestead

Tags: mysql, linux, vagrant, homestead

I'm using laravel homestead, and for purposes I need to have quick access to mysql `general_log_file` in my windows shared folder. I started with this:

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL general_log_file = '/home/vagrant/code/mysql.log';
```

I also removed `secure_file_priv` from mysql setting, now I get:

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "secure_file_priv";
+------------------+-------+
| Variable_name    | Value |
+------------------+-------+
| secure_file_priv |       |
+------------------+-------+
```

I even gave Give Root Privileges to mysql via [this](https://linoxide.com/give-normal-user-root-privileges/) method, but I still get this error:

```
Can't create/write to file '/home/vagrant/code/mysql.log' (OS errno 13 - Permission denied)
```

while trying:

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL general_log = 'ON';
```

any idea how can I solve this irritating problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know of two things to check that are likely causes. I've experienced both of these in a vagrant environment.

1. The directory is not writeable by the Linux uid of the `mysqld` process.
2. The Linux kernel is restricting the paths accessible to `mysqld` through Apparmor (Ubuntu or Debian) or SELinux (CentOS or RHEL). The error reported is a permission error, even if the file permissions appear to allow the mysql user to write to that location. You must either disable the apparmor/selinux or else configure it to allow the alternative location.

   Since you're only using a VM, I'd just disable it, unless you would like to learn how to configure it in case you need to do that in a non-VM environment.

---

PS:
`secure_file_priv` is totally irrelevant to this issue. That option affects only `LOAD DATA INFILE` and `SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE`.

Comment: Option 3, systemd defaults system services to have [ProtectHome=yes](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#ProtectHome=) resulting in a non-readable home directory. `systemctl edit mysql.service` with `[Service]\n
ProtectHome=false`.

Comment: Rather than disabling selinux, use it and set the file permissions properly. `semanage fcontext -a -t mysqld_db_t '/home/vagrant/code(/.*)?' && restorecon -Rv /home/vagrant/code`